# Proving union of countably infinite sets

Tags: functions

I am given this to prove:

Suppose A is countably inﬁnite, B is ﬁnite, and A and B are disjoint. Prove that A ∪ B is
countably inﬁnite.

Can I say this:

Define $f: \mathbb N \to A \cup B$ by

$$
f(j) = \begin{cases}
a_n&\mbox{ if } j\leq n\\
b_{j-n}&\mbox{ if } j\geq n+1
\end{cases}
$$

Then, the sequence $(f(1), f(2),...,f(n), f(n+1), f(n+2),\dots)$ is $(b_1,b_2,\dots b_n,a_1,a_2,\dots)$. Then, $f$ is a bijection, so $A\cup B$ is countably infinite.

I think that makes sense, but can someone point me in the right direction? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I suppose $ n $ is the number of elements in $ B $. You should note down where the $ a_i $s and $ b_i $s come from. Notation-wise they seem to be from $ A $ and $ B $ respectively, but your solution suggests that $ b_i \in A $ and $ a_i \in B $ which is a little confusing. Otherwise your solution looks sound.

Comment: The $f$ as defined produces $n$ times the element $a_n$, then the $b$'s in order, and is undefined for $j>2n$. The answer is completely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

While I *think* your idea is correct, I would not give you full points for it if it was an exam answer. The problems:

- What are $a_i$ and $b_i$? If they are elements of $A$ and $B$, then you should write that down.
- If $a_i$ are elements of $A$, and $b_i$ are elements of $b$, then $f$ is not well defined as you only map to $n$ elements of $A$ and to an infinite amound of elements from $B$, which is not possible since $B$ ins finite and $A$ is infinite.
- Your proof that $f$ is a bijection is lacking. It is fairly easy to see, but you made no effort to prove it. In fact (see previous comment), $f$ is not a bijection as it does not map to $a_{n+1}$ and is therefore not surjective.

Comment: My apologies, I switched them around now. But then, how can I prove that it is a bijection? I can see that it is, but I am having trouble proving it.

Comment: @J-Play Simple. You prove that it is injective (i.e. show that if $f(i) = f(j)$, then $i=j$) and that it is surjective (i.e., for every element $x\in A\cup B$, you show that there exists such a $n\in\mathbb N$ that $f(n)=x$)

Comment: Of course. Thanks!